# Python/PyQt reopening QWebView shows blank page

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qwebview, qwebkit

I have this problem with QWebView not showing anything after I rerun QAplication. This small snippet displys the problem:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtWebKit, QtCore

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
while True:
    browser = QtWebKit.QWebView()
    browser.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl('https://www.google.ca/#q=pyqt'))
    browser.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Upon running, the google search page for pyqt is shown, but once I close the widget, next one pops up as blank instead of the same search page. I was wondering what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: One question would be why you need to call app.exec_() several times. See the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why the page stays blank, but I'm certain you can easily achieve the same functionality without calling `QApplication.exec_()` multiple times.

An example achieving the same:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore, QtWebKit

class MyBrowser(QtWebKit.QWebView):

    closing = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.closing.emit()

class MyApp(QtCore.QObject):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def setup(self):
        self.browser = MyBrowser()
        self.browser.closing.connect(self.setup)
        self.browser.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl('https://www.google.ca/#q=pyqt'))
        self.browser.show()


app = QtGui.QApplication([])
a = MyApp()
a.setup()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm calling app.exec_() in a loop because in the real application I have a call to login window exec_() and then depending on the user I build a QMainWindow with all user-specific UI elements. When the user closes their window, a new login dialog is shown.

Comment: @etsinko But do you really need to call app.exec_() more than once or is there another way?

Comment: I can probably find the way to avoid calling app.exec_() repeatedly. It will involve changing the current codebase though. I really wonder why consecutive calls to app.exec_() affect webpage rendering.